# is it possible to know if a dijit is displayed or not?

Tags: javascript, dojo

i have two divs on a page.  each has several dijits.  i have atoggle that shows only one div or the other.  when i submit the form, i only want to validate the dijits that are in the div that is displayed.  is there a way to do this?  basically, and dijits that have "display:none" should not be validated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you hide a certain div element, try setting all of the dijits within that div to be disabled.  Dojo should ignore disabled elements during validation.

Also, disabled fields add to the accessibility of your app by keeping the elements unusable even when they're visible on browsers with no CSS support (`display: none` obviously doesn't work when the browser doesn't understand CSS).